# Asynchronous usage of cv::imshow

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I would like to get this functionality with OpenCV 4.5.3 and Python 3.7 on Raspberry Pi 4 with 2021-05-07-raspios-buster-armhf-full:

```
cv::imshow("window", img);
do_something_while_img_is_displayed();
cv::destroyWindow("window");
```

I tried 2 options after a call to `cv::imshow`:

1. `cv::waitKey(10)`
2. `cv::pollKey()`

both of which display only a window frame without an image

[image]

What is the way to accomplish it?

**NOTE**

My intent is to have an image persistently displayed on the screen and be able to call other OpenCV functions at that time, e.g. capture and process images from a camera. I don't care about event processing loop - there will be no UI interaction at that time.

Comment: your explanation of waitkey and pollkey is wrong. they do the same thing, namely run the event queue, except pollkey, on win32 only at the moment, doesn't keep running (and sleeping) but returns as soon as the event queue has been processed. both "display" a window. if they didn't, you didn't call imshow().

Comment: if you need to keep the gui responsive while doing something else, either use threads or keep calling waitKey/pollKey interleaved with your other processing.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz *your explanation of waitkey and pollkey is wrong* True, I edited the question. They display only a skeleton of the window as shown on the screen capture, though.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet works on Ubuntu 18.04 and on 2021-05-07-raspios-buster-armhf-full:

```
import cv2, sys, time

image = cv2.imread("t1-4.png")
cv2.imshow("window", image)
cv2.waitKey(1000) # this delay has to be long on RPi
time.sleep(3) # substitute for do something
cv2.destroyWindow("window")
```

Equivalent C++ code works on both OSes as well.

Comment: the sleep() call is going to be a problem because during those 3 seconds, the GUI library isn't given a chance to process events, which can cause the operating system (x server at least) to think your program is dead. also, the 1000 milliseconds to waitKey() are **not** required. that is simply how long you **choose** to wait before calling destroyWindow

Comment: besides, your answer doesn't actually answer your question, which was: "how to keep the GUI responsive while doing other processing in the main thread". that requires threading, or calling waitKey/pollKey *in* your processing.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz *1000 milliseconds to waitKey() are not required* Yes, they are on RPi. It takes almost that long for the desktop to produce a fully formed window with an image. Shorter delay produces only a standard size, empty window frame as shown on the screenshot in my question.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz *how to keep the GUI responsive* was not my question, *do_something_while_img_is_displayed* was. I don't care about event processing loop. I just want the image staying on the screen. I'm adding a note to clarify this.